# Button(s) KeyBinding [MVVM]

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am struggling to bind some short cut keys to my WPF buttons. The buttons are built up dynamically by using the following code [only a snippet - but should be sufficient]:

```
// for each command defined in the database
... 
PosCommand cmd = null; // FYI: PosCommand implements ICommand
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.AssemblyPath))
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(group.AssemblyPath))
    cmd = (PosCommand)Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.LoadFile(group.AssemblyPath).GetType(group.FullQualifiedName), model);
}
else
{
cmd = (PosCommand)Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(group.FullQualifiedName), model);
}
if (cmd == null)
continue;

Function function = new Function()
{
Command = cmd,
Name = group.FunctionName,
Description = group.Description,
FunctionCode = group.FunctionCode
};
...
```

Here is a snippet of the XAML which binds to the C# code:

```
<itemscontrol x:name="functionList" grid.row="0" itemssource="{Binding GroupFunctions}" xmlns:x="#unknown">
    <itemscontrol.itemtemplate>
        <datatemplate>
            <groupbox header="{Binding Group}">
                <itemscontrol scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility="Disabled" itemssource="{Binding Functions}">
                    <itemscontrol.itemspanel>
                        <itemspaneltemplate>
                            <wrappanel />
                        </itemspaneltemplate>
                    </itemscontrol.itemspanel>
                    <itemscontrol.itemtemplate>
                        <datatemplate>
                            <Button MinWidth="91" Height="50" Content="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Description}" Command="{Binding Command}"/> 
                        </datatemplate>
                    </itemscontrol.itemtemplate>
                </itemscontrol>
            </groupbox>
        </datatemplate>
    </itemscontrol.itemtemplate>
</itemscontrol>
```

I tried to add a some key binding to the button without any success?! I altered the Function class so that it contains properties for the Modifier and the Key, for each of the buttons of course. It still doesn't want to work, even if I hard code the Modifier and Key values??

```
<Button.InputBindings>
    <keybinding modifiers="{Binding Mod}" key="{MyKey}" />
</Button.InputBindings>
```

Could anyone please assist me in this matter?
Many thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, I wrote my own key listener. I handled the `KeyEventHandler`:

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{            
    base.OnInitialized(e);

    this.AddHandler(Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)HandleKeyDownEvent);
}

private void HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Basically, all of the ICommands are defined within the database and are built up dynamically. Thus, I made use of the CommandProperty to add a complex data type in. In this complex data type, I store a variety of information, include the short cut key to use. So the key listener waits for the key combination, looks it up and executes the ICommand.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `System.Windows.Interactivity` with a custom trigger. I have an [example here on my blog](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/05/02/InputBindingKeyBindingWithCaliburnMicro.aspx), done for the  Caliburn Micro  MVVM framework, but I think it is a cross framework solution. `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` is part of Blend, but it is redistributable in binary form, it does not requires any special setup, just an xcopy deploy is enough.

Comment: Hi Felice, Many thanks for the reply. I'll give it a try and let you know! Kind regards

Comment: This is a more reusable approach than writing a handler in the code behind of every UI component you write